# Horizontally and vertically scrollable layout in react native

Tags: android, react-native, grid, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to configure table grid layout in react native which could be scrollable horizontally and vertically.

By table grid layout I mean the layout similar to html table/tr/td: all views in the same row should have the same height and all views in the same column should have the same width.

The height of the row should be selected based on the height of the biggest view in the row.
The width of the column should be selected based on the width of the biggest view in the column.

I've started with horizontal scrolling.
This is what I've done:
https://snack.expo.io/@grekonstudio/01_initial
While it looks fine for me in the browser, on my device in looks this way:

[image]

The biggest column takes as much space as it needs and the rest of the space is shared between other columns. But it is done for each row independently, so columns border floats. Ideally, I want Row 1, Col 1 and Row 2, Col 1 to be the same size as Row 3, Col 1. That does not work as they and in different rows.

Well, obvious idea is to switch to column base layout, right:
https://snack.expo.io/@grekonstudio/04_column_based
Again, in the browser, it looks different. On the device it looks this way:

[image]

On the first look, this is exactly what I want! But apparently, it just moves the problem to another dimenstion. Let's make one View higher than the others, add a vertical ScrollView and we are losing row layout now:
https://snack.expo.io/@grekonstudio/05_same_problem

[image]

You can see the bigger cell takes all space and the rows are not having the same size anymore :(

Additionally, I tried two more things:

- setting the flex: 1 to Scroll's view contentContainerStyle.
  https://snack.expo.io/@grekonstudio/02_flex_1
  In this case, it does not scroll at all.

Getting device height and width and fixing the size of the scroll view contentContainerStyle
https://snack.expo.io/@grekonstudio/03_fixed_width
In this case 'flex: 1' works as it works without a scroll view: splitting it to equal size boxes, while I want rows and cols to be adjusted by content
Another disadvantage is hardcoding width: 2 * screenWigth as e.g. for small content I might not need 2 screen width, I might need 1.5 or 1.2 only. It would also not work in portrait easlity.

I've also tried using the DataTable component https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/data-table.html, but when added to horizontal scroll view it fails to keep table layout the same way as in my first image: cells in the same column have different width.

Does anyone have a solution for the above?